# Cordova: Add native code without plugins in config.xml

Tags: java, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

How can I add android native code to a Cordova based project without creating a plugin? what are the entries to put in config.xml?

I'm asking because I have native code that I want to add which is specific to my project and I don't want to always have to remove and re-add the plugin, it will also make svn cycles more complicated.

Is it even possible?

The only part in config.xml that I see that might be related are-

```
<feature name="NiceNativeFeature">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.mycomp.plugins.YourClass"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want keeping using cordova?

Comment: @malcubierre Sure, I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you are not making a plugin dont modify the xml.

Comment: @MisterSmith, config.xml is meant to be edited, for example, the name of your app, the id, any permissions for android's manifest to name a few. it's also mentioned in Cordova's documentation "an app's behavior can be controlled with a global configuration file, config.xml" https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html

Comment: @AlonAmir You can add as many Java classes as you need to your proyect, ONLY if you made a custom plugin should you need to include it in the xml.